# How can I extract an imported python module to a file?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, 3dsmax

I have a module that I can import, but I can't find out where it is saved because `module.__file__` doesn't work on it.

I'm trying to set up VSCode for 3ds Max python development and the pymxs module is hidden somewhere where intellisense and pylint can't find it. As such, I get errors every time I use it and autocomplete doesn't work. However, the code runs fine and i can use `inspect.getmembers()` on it perfectly.

I would like to save the whole module into a text file, so that intellisense/pylint hopefully will be able to read it.

Is that possible?

Comment: "`module.__file__` doesnt work on it [...] so I get errors every time i use it" <- this is not a very helpful error description.

Comment: the errors arent relevant. What I need is a module.py file of the module. There isnt one, but i can still import module, so im wondering if there is some reverse functionality like export module or something?

Comment: Execute `python -vc'import pymxs' |& grep pymxs` and include the output in the question.

Comment: Im not having any luck getting that to work. it says `& unexpected at this time` Ive figured out the first part, but what does |& do? and grep is unix right? im trying to run this in windows shell

Comment: Oh OK. Well I don't know how to grep in windows. But you should find the import loader in the output of `python -vc'import pymxs'` somewhere.

Comment: It sounds like pymxs is an extension module provided by 3ds Max and so there's not going to be any Python code to export to get IntelliSense for.

Answer (score 1):

The file pymxs.py unfortunately doesn't exist, the module only exists at runtime, i.e. when running your script in 3ds max. So at this point there's no existing solution to get autocomplete for pymxs in an external editor.

In the editor inside 3ds max however they have autocomplete these days, so maybe (just maybe) it's possible to create a plugin that communicates with max and retrieves this information during runtime, but no idea where you would even start with that, or if it's even possible.

Another solution could be to create wrapper functions for your most commonly used pymxs functions, and in that way get autocomplete from your wrapper library. Note however that with this approach everything in pymxs might not be possible to add here as it is using runtime information. Let's for example say you run `myobject = rt.selection[0]` Depending on if `myobject` becomes a teapot or a box or whatever at runtime, different functions will be available, such as radius and height. If you know what you will get maybe you can cast the output to your wrapper class or something like that.